# Comment edit request

Tags: support, comments

I've placed a comment with a link to an image that displays my full personal name. I want to replace the image in the comment, but I posted it longer than 5 minutes ago. (which is a unreasonably short time to edit comments btw).

How can I edit the comment or can anyone edit it for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lol why didn't I think about that? xD Thx Richard!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments can always be deleted by their owner, if you wish to edit a comment after the 5 minute limit simply delete the old one and post a new one.

Comment editing is limited because (unlike questions and answers) they have a sense of "time", comments are often replies to each other and constant editing of them could lead to confusion. Additionally comments do not have revision histories so there is no way to rectify any confusion should a comment be edited to include information that is discussed later in the thread of comments.

No restriction on editing could also allow a backdoor for spam; post legitimate comments then later edit them as spam with no notifications to the post owner or even worse find comments from other users seeming to reply to and agree with the spam.

Comment: Thx for explaining why there's a short edit time. Will accept the answer in 8 minutes :)

Comment: Also worth to mention that unlike questions and answers, comments do not have revisions so users can't see previous versions of a comment. I can now edit this to say something totally different, and if not limited to 5 minutes it can become REALLY confusing not to mention spam. (passive spammer can post 100 legit comments, wait for few days then suddenly edit them all to be spam links - nobody will ever notice)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd A fair point, added

Comment: @RichardTingle cheers, see my comment edit. ;)